# Using multiple nested if else statements in R with a variety of criteria is only returning the first two necessary values?

Tags: r

I am trying to use R to create a new data frame column that takes into account multiple values from two different columns in the data frame.

I created an example dataframe.

```
exampleGender <- c("M","F","M","M","F","F")
exampleChoice <- c("P","Q","R","Q","P","R")
example.data<-data.frame(exampleGender,exampleChoice)
```

This is my code. I am trying to use nested ifelse statements to accomplish this. The issue is, when I run it, it only returns labels from the first two ifelse statements I used - basically, it gets 'exampleGender' correct, but only uses the first value for 'exampleChoice'. What I want it to do is return a separate label that considers both 'exampleChoice' and 'exampleGender'. Does anyone know how to make the code take into account all of the different criteria, as opposed to only the first two?

```
example.data$Label <- ifelse(example.data$exampleChoice=="P" | 
example.data$exampleGender=="M","Male_P",
ifelse(example.data$exampleChoice=="P"| 
example.data$exampleGender=="F","Female_P",                                           
ifelse(example.data$exampleChoice=="Q" | 
example.data$exampleGender=="M","Male_Q",                                                    
ifelse(example.data$exampleChoice=="Q" | 
example.data$exampleGender=="F","Female_Q",                                                           
ifelse(example.data$exampleChoice=="R" | 
example.data$exampleGender=="M","Male_R",                                                                  
ifelse(example.data$exampleChoice=="R" | 
example.data$exampleGender=="F","Female_R","NA"))))))
```

Thanks. I hope this isn't redundant/asked before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap `|` for `&`:

```
exampleGender <- c("M","F","M","M","F","F")
exampleChoice <- c("P","Q","R","Q","P","R")
example.data<-data.frame(exampleGender,exampleChoice)

example.data$Label <- ifelse(example.data$exampleChoice=="P" & example.data$exampleGender=="M","Male_P",
                             ifelse(example.data$exampleChoice=="P"& example.data$exampleGender=="F","Female_P",                                           
                                    ifelse(example.data$exampleChoice=="Q" & example.data$exampleGender=="M","Male_Q",                                                    
                                           ifelse(example.data$exampleChoice=="Q" & example.data$exampleGender=="F","Female_Q",                                                           
                                                  ifelse(example.data$exampleChoice=="R" & example.data$exampleGender=="M","Male_R",                                                                  
                                                         ifelse(example.data$exampleChoice=="R" & example.data$exampleGender=="F","Female_R","NA"))))))

> example.data
  exampleGender exampleChoice    Label
1             M             P   Male_P
2             F             Q Female_Q
3             M             R   Male_R
4             M             Q   Male_Q
5             F             P Female_P
6             F             R Female_R
```

You can also use `tidyverse` and `case_when()` to avoid nested `ifelse()` statements.

```
library(tidyverse)

exampleGender <- c("M","F","M","M","F","F")
exampleChoice <- c("P","Q","R","Q","P","R")
example.data<-data.frame(exampleGender,exampleChoice)

example.data %>%
  mutate(
    Label = case_when(
      exampleChoice=="P" & exampleGender=="M" ~ "Male_P",
      exampleChoice=="P" & exampleGender=="F" ~ "Female_P",                                           
      exampleChoice=="Q" & exampleGender=="M" ~ "Male_Q",                                                    
      exampleChoice=="Q" & exampleGender=="F" ~ "Female_Q",                                                           
      exampleChoice=="R" & exampleGender=="M" ~ "Male_R",                                                                  
      exampleChoice=="R" & exampleGender=="F" ~ "Female_R",
      TRUE ~ as.character("NA")))

  exampleGender exampleChoice    Label
1             M             P   Male_P
2             F             Q Female_Q
3             M             R   Male_R
4             M             Q   Male_Q
5             F             P Female_P
6             F             R Female_R
```